# Inequality $(\alpha f,g)_{L^2}\leq C\|\alpha\|_{W}\|f\|_{H^{1/2}}\|g\|_{H^{3/2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $f\in H^{1/2}(S)$, $g\in H^{3/2}(S)$, $\alpha\in L^\infty(S)$, where $S$ is a closed smooth $n$-dimensional surface (e.g, $n$-dimensional sphere).

Problem: to find such Banach space $W$ that the estimate
\begin{gather}\tag{1}\label{1}
(\alpha f,g)_{L^2(S)}\leq C\|\alpha\|_{W}\|f\|_{H^{1/2}(S)}\|g\|_{H^{3/2}(S)},
\end{gather}
holds; here $C>0$ in independent of $f,g,\alpha$. Evidently, the above estimate holds
for $W=L^\infty(S)$, namely, one has
$$
(\alpha f,g)_{L^2(S)}\leq \|\alpha\|_{L^\infty(S)}\|f\|_{L^2(S)}\|g\|_{L^2(S)}\leq \|\alpha\|_{L^\infty(S)}\|f\|_{H^{1/2}(S)}\|g\|_{H^{3/2}(S)}.$$
Question: what is the largest space $W$ for which \eqref{1} holds? Or, at least, can one give an example of $W$ satisfying \eqref{1} and being indeed  larger than $L^\infty(S)$
(e.g., some Sobolev space with negative index)?

Comment: In $\Bbb R^d$, using Fourier transform, it seems $W=H^{-2}$

Comment: Thanks, I will try